# Is this an Emperor Penguin or a King Penguin?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I have a book from *Dorling Kindersley* called *Animal Encyclopedia* (the German version that I have is called *Das große Tierlexikon*) with images from animals.

One is titled *Emperor Penguin* (*Kaiserpinguin*) which is in my opinion clearly recognizable as a *King Penguin* (*Königspinguin*).

This is the image:
[image: Emperor or King]

I wrote to Dorling Kindersley and they told my that their investigation revealed that it really is an *Emperor Penguin*.

I am not a biologist nor a penguin expert, but from all the descriptions and images I could find (even in the same book on other pages!) I think the publishing company is wrong and just too lazy or arrogant to admit this error and too miserly to release a revised version of the book.

Who is wrong? Me or *Dorling Kindersley*? Emperor or King?

### Update 2020

They seem to inherently admit it themselves, that the book was wrong (and that they lied to me), as they used the same picture on one of their [websites](https://www.dkfindout.com/us/animals-and-nature/birds/penguins/) and with **king penguin** in the caption of the picture:
[image: image on the website of Dorling Kindersley / DK]

Comment: I know this is verrrryyy old. But yes it's a king. You can tell from the long straight beak. Emperors have a shorter curved beak

Comment: @erik Haha love the update. Much appreciated after 7 years of personal torment I'm sure! :p.  Seriously, though, thanks for updating!

Comment: Might I also suggest just accepting Alan's answer here or adding one of your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this image [here](http://www.acuteaday.com/blog/tag/difference-between-emperor-and-king-penguin/). I've also seen references to the "closed orange ear patch" of the King Penguin, which fits with the image. So my vote is for the DK image being a King Penguin.

[image]

Comment: Are you an expert at this? Ornithologist or something? That would be of more value for me. I have the same opinion as you have because of the closed orange ear patch. But maybe there are other indicators which are not that obvious for us amateurs.

Comment: No I'm not an expert, just an amateur like you.